# Can't log in to SQL Server 2008 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I think something happened to an mdf file on disk.
When I try to start SQL Server Mgmt Studio (SQL Server 2008, Win 7 x64), I get an error:
"Cannot open user default database."
Since I can't connect at all, how do I fix this?
I have tried connecting to other dbs using osql, but always get an error.

Thanks for any workarounds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is via command line. You keep opening connections using SSMS that fail...

Using command line you'll have one connection and **delimit the login name correctly: "[SVR\USR]"**

```
sqlcmd -S InstanceName -d master -E -Q"ALTER LOGIN [SVR\USR] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = master"
```

or replace `-E` with `-U SQLLogin -P Password` if you have a SQL login handy

Comment: Thank you.  Specifying the server\user correctly seems to have been the key.

Answer (score 1):

When connecting from Management studio, In the "connect to server" dialog box, before connecting, click "Options" and change the "Connect to database" dialog box to "master".

Comment: That gets me in to the Object Browser, but anything else I try to do gets me the same message: "Cannot open user default database".  
Can't open my login to change the default db...

Comment: Oh... Modify the "default database" in the login. Expand "Security", "Logins", Right click on your login and choose Properties. You'll see the "default database" in the "General" tab.

Comment: Tried that.  Result:
Cannot show requested dialog.
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
Cannot show requested dialog. (SqlMgmt)
------------------------------
Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
------------------------------
Failed to connect to server (local). (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
------------------------------
Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'svr\usr'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 4064)

Comment: This is farkled.  When I try to attach another db, I get this:
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------
Cannot show requested dialog.
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
Parameter name: nColIndex
Actual value was -1. (Microsoft.SqlServer.GridControl)

Comment: oh boy... If you are using "Windows Authentication", open Management studio as an admin and then try to do what I said before...

Comment: No joy.  Right-click SQL Svr Mgmt Studio, Run as Administrator.
Same result when trying to modify svr\usr account.
Same result trying to modify db1.
With Windows Auth, can't change user name (why not?).

Answer (score 0):

Login as an administrator and change your default database: `ALTER LOGIN ... WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = ...`. If you're not an administrator, ask an administrator to do it. If you must log in in the database in question, ask an administrator to investigate whi the database is offline.

Comment: All that would be nice if there were an administrator to ask.
Logging in as administrator would be easy, if there were an admin account other than my login.
I am running SQL Server 2008 on my laptop.  All dbs are local.  I believe the problem started when a .mdf, attached in SQL Server, got corrupted.  Since it was the default db for my login, I can't log in.

Comment: I tried doing this with osql:
>osql -E -q "alter login svr\usr with DEFAULT_DATABASE=db1"
Login failed for user 'svr\usr'.
Cannot open user default database. Login failed.

Comment: Tried sqlcmd, too:
>sqlcmd -E -d master
1> ALTER LOGIN SVR\USR WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=MASTER
2> GO
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server SVR, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '\'.
1>

Comment: Stop the SQL Server, restart it in administrative single user mode (`sqlservr -m -sMSSQLSERVER`), the log in as a laptop administrator, fix your login, restart the SQL.